# How to add images on second row after button click if first row is filled

Tags: android, image

I want to add images on button click in a row wise manner and if first row is filled then it should starts with next row .

I have defined scroll view horizontally with linear layout and it is adding horizontally but I want that the image should be added in next row if first row is already full, then it should starts with second row if second row has full then it should starts with third row and so on .

How can i do this ?

```
package neeraj.com.images;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LinearLayout linearLayout1;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);


    }

    public void onClick(View v){

        ImageView image = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
            image.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        linearLayout1.addView(image);


    }



}
```

xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Button" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hsv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:measureAllChildren="false"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </HorizontalScrollView>





</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this might help, use [Predicate Layout](https://github.com/rajandev17/BookMyDrive/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/ggktech/bookmydrive/PredicateLayout.java) as your wrapper and add images to it dynamically.

**Predicate Layout will automatically move image into second row when first row is filled.**

Download the PredicateLayout.java file and paste it in your project.

**Usage**

```
 <PredicateLayout
            android:id="@+id/image_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp">
        </PredicateLayout>
```

**Java**

```
predicateLayout = (PredicateLayout) findViewById(R.id.image_container);
predicateLayout.addView(imageView); // add images on click
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you Should go with the Grid View, and Keep on adding the path to the GridView Adapted on the Button Click. Once you add the Path to the Adapter, use notifySetDataChange() to reflect the change.